# Laravel Relationship with WHERE clause returns nothing

Tags: laravel, relational-database

> I have `areas`. Each `area` have `N curses`
>   So, each `curse` belongsTo only `one area`.

#### My class

```
class Area extends Model
{
    public function curses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Curse');
    }
}
```

#### My Controller

```
public function getCursesByAreaId()
    {
        $areaId = Input::get('areaId'); //ID of selected Area
        //area_id is a field of table CURSE. A FK to Area.
        $areas  = Area::with('curses')->where('area_id', $areaId)->get();  
        foreach($areas as $area)
        {
            var_dump($areas);
        }       

    }
```

#### Curse Model

```
class Curseextends Model
{
    protected $fillable =
    [
        'description',
        'area_id'
    ];
}
```

Using the laravel's debugbar, I see that the query being executed is this:

```
select * from "areas" where "area_id" = '2'
```

Isn't it supose to run the relational query ? (with the joins)

Already checked if I'm receiving the right `id` and it's ok.
the problem is that it's bringing no data at all.

Comment: You are typing `var_dump($area->cursos)` but your relation says `curses`. Is it a typo? Moreover try to type `where` first then write `with` something like this: `$areas  = Area::where('area_id', $areaId)->with('curses')->get();`

Comment: @NitishKumar Yes, sorry. Actually I'm doing `var_dump($areas)`. But I get "This request has no response data avaliable".

Comment: Could you please share Curse Model.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi Of course. Already done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like the following:

```php
$areas = Area::whereHas('curses', function($query) use ($areaId) {
    $query->where('area_id', $areaId);
})
->with('curses')
->get();
```

The `whereHas` is required only if you want to get the areas that has matching curses.

But, I think you can do it like this way if you only need the related curses because one curse only belong to a single area so, if have the area then you'll get all the curses attached to it:

```php
$area = Area::with('curses')->find($areaId); // Single area

// Access the curses
$curses = $area->curses; // collection of curses
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'` On the first `->whereHas()`.   
Is it really this complicated? I thought my join (`hasMnay()`) would ease things when bringing data from relation :\

Comment: Fixed the typo just now. There was a missing semicolon :-)

Comment: Thanks ! But i'm getting a `Status Code:500 Internal Server Error`. D:

Comment: Check the code and make sure there is no other errors. Check the error on your network tab.

Comment: Amazing. Is there a way to work directly with `curses` without doing two  `foreach()` ? One for `$areas as $area` and other for `area->curse as $curse`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using relational `area_id` which is present in `curse` table, try retrieving the ID of area by `id` not by `area_id`, something like this:

```
$areas  = Area::where('id', $areaId)->with('curses')->get();
```

Hope you get the solution.

Comment: But I thought that my relation (`hasMany()`) Would work join both tables and I would be able to bring data from that join.

Comment: Nope, first of all you have to retrieve the `Area` model in which table has `id`, then relation table of `curse` will be retrieved from `with` statement. for more information you can check eager loading in documentation.

Comment: As I have only ONE area and many curses that belongs to that area. Why I can't do `$areas->curses`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$areas = Area::whereHas('curses', function($area_query) use ($area_id) {
    $area_query->where('area_id', $area_id)
})
->with('curses')
->get();
```